# Date Pager in Drupal 8

Tags: views, 8, datetime, paging

How can I implement a date pager (e.g. as a contextual filter) in Drupal 8 on a custom entity field?

It seems to me, that the date_views functionality didn't make it into the core yet, and I can't activate the module date api module (8.x-1.x-dev) or date_views module individually (and I don't really know why that is so).